# Create files from text in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I was try to use create files based on text in a file. Following is snippet of file:

```
//logging {
  //        channel default_debug {
  //                file "data/named.run";
  //                severity dynamic;
  //        };
  //};

logging {
    channel default_file {
        file "/var/log/named/default.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
    };
```

There is about 15 files that need to be created and although not terribly tedious to do by hand I would like to understand how to script this task.
I first was trying to tackle problem by using awk to output to a new file the fourth field of /var/log/named/general.log. 
Code I was trying:

```
 awk -F"/" '{print $4}' named.conf > test.conf
```

However this does not appear to output desired text. If I just copy and paste:

```
  channel default_file {
    file "/var/log/named/default.log" versions 3 size 5m;
    severity dynamic;
    print-time yes;
    };
```

and then run

```
 awk -F"/" '{print $5}' named1.conf
```

I receive this output

```
 default.log" versions 3 size 5m;
```

I would like to create the file named the "default.log" from file "/var/log/named/default.log"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What output were you hoping to receive?

Comment: That would help, I would like to create individual files named default.log, all files I want to create will be after /var/log/named/*

Comment: Do you want to create `/var/log/named/default.log` or `./default.log`

Comment: Don't want to be greedy but both would be nice. I guess the full path would be good. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    # skip comments
    /^[[:blank:]]*\/\// {next} 

    # look for files
    $1 == "file" {
        gsub(/^"|"$/, "", $2)    # remove leading and trailing quotes
        print $2
        n = split($2, a, "/")    # find the basename of the file
        print a[n]
    }
' named.conf
```

Given your sample input, this will print:

```
/var/log/named/default.log
default.log
```

The equivalent sed

```
sed -n '
    /^[[:blank:]]*file "/ {
        s///                   # delete what was just matched
        s/".*//                # delete the quote and the following text
        p
        s!.*/!!                # delete the path part
        p
    }
' named.conf
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am receiving syntax errors. I tried running  
awk ' /^[[:blank:]]*\/\// {next} $1 == "named.conf" { gsub(/^"|"$/, "", $2) print $2 n = split($2, a, "/") print a[n]} ' > test.conf

Comment: No, `$1 == "file"` matches the line where "file" is the first word. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the string `default.log`, without the rest of the line, you can change your field separator:

```
awk -F'[/"]+' 'NF>1{print $5}' named.conf
```

The condition `NF>1` prevents the rest of the lines in the file from resulting in blank output.